# std::lower_bound() vs std::map::lower_bound()

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, lower-bound

The [lower_bound](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) function of algorithms library takes a forward iterator and returns the lower bound. It works fine for vectors but when i used it for a map, I got compiler error. My doubt is that std::map supports bidirectional iterators which can obviously act as forward iterators, so why std::lower_bound(map.begin(),map.end(),int value) doesn't work but the member function of map class, map.lower_bound(int value) works for a map? Here is some example code for reference

```
    #include<bits/stdc++.h>
    using namespace std;
    int main(){
    
    vector<int>v = {1,1,1,2,3,4,2,3,2,5,6,12,12,9};
    map<int,int>mp;
    for(auto x:v)mp[x]++;
    
    for(int i=0;i<15;i++){
    
    auto it = mp.lower_bound(i); // this works
 //   auto it = lower_bound(mp.begin(),mp.end(),i) //this doesn't work
    if(it!=mp.end())
    cout<<i<<" lower bound is "<<it->first<<" and its frequency in vector is "<<it->second<<endl;
    
    
    }
    
    
    return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything you need can be found in the documentation

- [std::lower_bound](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound)
- [std::map::lower_bound](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/lower_bound).

`std::lower_bound` expects a **sorted** range of N values of type `T` given by the iterators and `T` value to search for.

- If the iterators are random access, it is the slightly modified binary search to get the lower bound as specified. Therefore the complexity is logarithmic in N.
- If the iterators are just bidirectional, the complexity is linear in `N`.

`std::map<Key,Value>::lower_bound` expects `Key` key to search for and the complexity is logarithmic in `N` because it performs binary search on the red-black tree, although that is technically an implementation detail.

So, `std::lower_bound` does not work for you because the map contains `pair<const Key,Value`>, not just `Key`, the following will work

```
auto it = lower_bound(mp.begin(),mp.end(),std::pair<const int,int>{9,1});
```

but the complexity is linear and of course it is not very useful if you only want to search using keys. `std::map::lower_bound` solves both problems. Although the latter could have been solved by custom `Compare` function.

This pattern is common to all containers and algorithms, there is e.g. generic `std::find` and specialized `container::find` for each container that is *better*.

Please, do not use `#include<bits/stdc++.h>`.

Answer (score 1):

The member function exists because the algorithm's function doesn't work. The element type of `map` is `pair<const K, T>`. The algorithm's function isn't aware of how to compare only key parts of values.